# Picture of Space Layout

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $W_1+W_2$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $W_1$ and $W_2$, then how should this be represented pictorially? Also, how do I prove that $W_1+W_2$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $W_1$ and $W_2$? Can this be reworded in another way? How can this be stated in terms of span?

Comment: Do you need an impressionist, cubist, or surrealist point of view?

Comment: A perfectionist point of view would be nice.

Comment: By the way, how is this fact true?

Comment: I assume $V$ is a vector space, and $W_1$ and $W_2$ subspaces of $V$, right? In that case a Venn-diagram-like picture would be good enough in my opinion. You may also want to google-image "intersection of subspaces."

Comment: Which fact do you mean?

Comment: That $W_1 + W_2$ is the intersection ...

Comment: Your assumption is right.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it depends on how you want to draw it, and what size V is.  But if I were to draw this pictorially I would create a plane and draw two vectors in them, label the plane V and the vectors W1 and W2.  Now these two vectors actually represent larger spaces, but can you draw in 4,5,6,...,n dimensions?  This is the best we can do.  Interesting side note, we can actually find an angle between W1 and W2. This does actually have a significant meaning too. :)[image: W1+W2]

Answer (score 1):

To prove $W_1 + W_2$ is the intersection, first show that any subspace containing $W_1$ and $W_2$ must contain $W_1 + W_2$.  Then show that $W_1 + W_2$ is in fact a subspace which contains $W_1$ and $W_2$.